# An example of a subset of N which intersects every set of form {a + nd : n ∈ N}, a, d ∈ N, is (b) {$k^2$: k ∈ N} or (c) {k + k! : k ∈ N}

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

An example of a subset of N which intersects every set of form $\{a + nd : n \in \mathbb N\}$, where
$a, d \in \mathbb N$, is

(a) $\{2k : k \in \mathbb N\}$.      (b) $\{k^2: k \in\mathbb N\}$.

(c) $\{k + k! : k \in \mathbb N\}$ (d) $\{k + k^2
: k \in\mathbb N\}$

options (a) and (d) can be eliminated as they are subsets of even numbers .

And they don't intersect the set of the form $\{1+2n :n \in\mathbb N\}$

I can't do anything with (b) and (c).

Please give a hint.

Comment: Why did you put `$` signs only around $k^2$?

Comment: @EspeciallyLime: Don't forget the title! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what are the possible last digits of perfect squares?

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate (b) because the set $\{3n+2: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ doesn't contain any squares. On the other hand, $(a+d)+(a+d)!$ shows up in $\{a+dn: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ regardless of $a,d,$ so option (c) is correct although you wouldn't have to prove this for a multiple choice test.